# Unit testing with chai-as-promised: how to test for two possible errors with rejectedWith()?

Tags: truffle, mocha, unittesting

I am new to asking questions here and I am sorry if my question is not correctly asked!

I am currently testing some smart contracts with truffle and have some problems with testing for exceptions. At the beginning I have used only mocha and chai, but I found chai-as-promised and I thought the tests are going to be more readable after extending them with chai-as-promised. 
In my case I have implemented the method:

```
function testForThrow(error) {   return error.toString().indexOf("out of gas") != -1 || error.toString().indexOf("invalid opcode") != -1; }
```

because the possible error messages are two – “out of gas” or “invalid opcode”. And one test look like this:

```
}).catch(function(error) {
      assert(testForThrow(error), "expecting throw");
});
```

So my problem: chai- as-promised provides the function rejectedWith() but with this function we can test only one possible output, and I can’t come up with solution, because there is no OR in mocha and chai..

Current state of the test declaration with chai-as-promised:

```
.should.be.rejectedWith("invalid opcode");
```

Have someone idea how can I do this or the first version is the only possible way?